# T-SQL Find records that are partially appeared in a paragraph

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, string-matching

Suppose there are two tables like:

**Table1:**

ID ___ Content

11 ___ Apple iPhone is a great electronic device.

12 ___ Samsung galaxy offers good capabilities.

**Table2:**

ID ___ Title

71___ Refurbished Nokia 3310

72___ Brand-New iPhone 6

73___ Alcatel T-Phone

I want to create a query that receives an ID from `Table1` (like 11) and returns records from `Table2` that contain words from Content column of `Table1` (here: 72).

I have enabled Full-Text and though too much to find an effective and quick way to create the query, but even did not found a clue to start. I was avoiding parsing sentences to words via WHILE or splitting them and I think there must be a correct way to handle this.

Thanks for your help and please let me know if further clarification is required.

Comment: you want to do this in simple select or procedure?

Comment: @Whencesoever procedure.

Comment: @Whencesoever It is OK if it spans over multiple lines or statements.

Comment: I answered the qestion. Works with Your data in my tables. Check it out ; ).

Comment: @Whencesoever Thank you very much. I am examining it right now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. It might not be the fastest or the cleanest one, but looks like it works. I decided to use ' ' (space) as words splitter.

First we need to create split function that splits text into words:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[f_SplitVarchar]
    (
      @RowData NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
      @SplitOn NVARCHAR(5)
    )
RETURNS @ReturnValue TABLE ( Data NVARCHAR(MAX) )
AS 
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @Counter INT
        SET @Counter = 1 
        WHILE ( CHARINDEX(@SplitOn, @RowData) > 0 ) 
            BEGIN  
                INSERT  INTO @ReturnValue
                        ( data
                        )
                        SELECT  Data = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@RowData, 1,
                                                             CHARINDEX(@SplitOn,
                                                              @RowData) - 1)))
                SET @RowData = SUBSTRING(@RowData,
                                     CHARINDEX(@SplitOn, @RowData) + 1,
                                     LEN(@RowData)) 
            SET @Counter = @Counter + 1  
        END 
    INSERT  INTO @ReturnValue
            ( data )
            SELECT  Data = LTRIM(RTRIM(@RowData))  
    RETURN  
END;
```

Then use it to get our data:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE prc

AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    declare @TEMP table (IDTable1 int, IDTable2 int)


        DECLARE @etd TABLE
        (
          words nvarchar(max) 
        )


        declare @idtable1 int, @Content nvarchar(max), @word nvarchar(max)

        declare k cursor local forward_only for select [ID]
      ,[Content] from Table1

      OPEN k;
FETCH NEXT FROM k INTO @idtable1 , @Content
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
    BEGIN


        delete from @etd

        insert into @etd (words)
        select * from  dbo.f_SplitVarchar(@Content,' ')

        declare k1 cursor local forward_only for select words from @etd

          OPEN k1;
    FETCH NEXT FROM k1 INTO @word
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
        BEGIN


        insert into @TEMP select @idtable1, ID from Table2 where ' ' + title + ' ' like '% ' + @word + ' %'


        FETCH NEXT FROM k1 INTO @word
        END

        close k1
        deallocate k1



        FETCH NEXT FROM k INTO @idtable1 , @Content
        END

        close k
        deallocate k
    select * from @TEMP
END
GO
```

At the end simply `Exec prc` will select ID from Table1 with ID from table 2 that contains the words from first table. If You need any more help or You don't understand anything just ask = ).

Comment: Thank you very much. Working solution!